# Newbie: Making sense Javascript closure example on MDN

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm very new to Javascript and I have been reading about [closures on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Closures). While I understood the first two code snippets on that link, I am confused by the syntax used in the third example that I have copied here.

```
    var getCode = (function(){
         var secureCode = "0]Eal(eh&2"; 

         return function () {
             return secureCode;
         };
     })();

     getCode();    // Returns the secureCode
```

What is the purpose of wrapping the outer function within parentheses followed by empty parentheses and a semi-colon? What does this syntax mean or what does it serve? Why not write it as follows instead?

```
    var getCode = function() {
         var secureCode = "0]Eal(eh&2"; 

         return function () {
             return secureCode;
         }
    };

    getCode();    // Returns the secureCode
```

Comment: The answer to your first question is **no**.  There's a function inside the first set of parentheses; that's not the same (at all) as there being *nothing* inside the parentheses.

Comment: If you hit F12 to open the dev tools, and paste in your first example, you will get a syntax error

Comment: guys, thanks. I just updated my question for clarity. Does my version of code snippet not serve same purpose as the original snippet?

Comment: @user710843 no, it doesn't.  In the first version, the parentheses wrapped around the outer anonymous function are not necessary, but the `()` before the final semicolon (before the call to `getCode()`) are necessary. That last `()` means that the anonymous function is **called**, so that the value of "getCode" is that function that's returned from inside the outer function. Your code does not involve that function call, so your "getCode" is the **outer** function, not the inner one.

Comment: *What is the purpose of wrapping the outer function within parentheses followed by empty parentheses and a semi-colon?* The empty parentheses at the end cause the function to be invoked.

Comment: @Ponty, Great. Your comment made me understand the part that the anonymous function needs to get executed in order to return the inner function. If you added this to answer, I will upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the example is that `secureCode` is like a private variable. After the function in parenthesis has executed, `secureCode` isn't in scope and so cannot be written to; but the *returned function* still has access to the variable and can be used as a getter.

Answer (score 0):

In other words you are encapsulating the secure code variable to a CONST. It can't be written to and thus altered, yet it's available through the getter to read from.